# Python - find length of sublists in a list, ignoring empty entries

Tags: python, list, sublist

So it's easy enough to determine the length of the sublists of a list with:

`list_length = [len(w) for w in data]`

But is there a way to get the length while ignoring any empty list entries: `''`?

I have a list of lists, `[data]`, and one of the sublists looks like this:

`['GOM COD', '60', '$2.00', '', '$120.00']`

So `list_length` is determined to be `5`. Until now, I would then turn the list of lists into a single list in order to remove all `''` entries, and then turn it back into a list of lists based on whatever value `list_length` is. In this case, however, after the removal of all `''`s, the `list_length` value of `5` ends up being incorrect and creates a messy DataFrame.

I do try to remove all empty string entries with `data = list(filter(None, data))` but that removes only those sublists that are made up entirely of `''`.

So I would like to ultimately be able to determine the length of a sublist while ignoring or excluding `''`s, because I have to run this code on many files so it has to be robust enough to read a correct `list_length`.

Is what I'm asking possible? Or even the smartest approach to this?

Thanks.

Comment: You mentioned a data frame... You should just load your data and then eliminate empty strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you're applying the `filter` at the wrong level. I personally prefer list comprehension over `filter` in most cases:

```
[len([x for x in w if x != '']) for w in data]
```

Using filter:

```
[len(list(filter(None, w))) for w in data]
```

**EDIT**

This is more efficient, since it doesn't have to construct a new list:

```
[sum(1 for x in w if x != '') for w in data]
```

To clear up confusion happening in the comments, remember that we're given a *list of lists*. Here's a valid input:

```
data = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', '', 'e'],
]
```

The value of any of the above expressions with this `data` is `[3, 2]`, because the first sublist has 3 non-empty strings, and the second sublist has 2 non-empty strings.

Comment: [7, 2, 5, 0, 7] This is the output of your current code, meaning also empty lists get evaluated.

Comment: Did you want to not count empty lists? You could just filter the output, then.

Comment: Wrong OP... and I do believe empty lists are to be counted.

Comment: @colspeed I do believe so too. But the title is: find length of sublists in a list, ignoring empty entries.

Comment: Oh. Now I'm super confused. @narn who are you and where did `[7, 2, 5, 0, 7]` come from? :-)

Comment: I think the "ignoring empty entries" is about empty entries in the sublists. Not empty sublists.

Comment: I'm a SO user, nice to meet you. And I got that list as an output when I used provided set from OP and your code snippet.

Comment: [len([x for x in w ]) for w in data if w !=''] gives [7, 2, 5, 7] excluding the zero length item

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked perfect. You're right though about `filter` being applied on the wrong level, I also end up applying it once the list of lists is one single list, but at that point I lose the information about how long each sublist was. Your solution was great, and simple enough to understand, thanks a bunch.

Comment: @narn We've only been given one sublist. It looks like you applied this code to just that.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony strange. `In [6]: data = ['GOM COD', '60', '$2.00', '', '$120.00']` `In [7]: [len([x for x in w if x != '']) for w in data]`
`Out[7]: [7, 2, 5, 0, 7]` Using Ipython on Python 3.5.3

Comment: @narn You ran different code than Rolf suggested. In any case, you're both misunderstanding the question. See my edit, which will hopefully clear this up.

Answer (score 1):

Using map,

```
data = ['GOM COD', '60', '$2.00', '', '$120.00']
[x for x in map(len, data) if x!=0]
```

Or using filter :

```
[len(x) for x in list(filter(lambda x: x != '', data))]
```

Or using map and filter :

```
map(len, list(filter(lambda x: x != '', data)))
```

Using list comprehension :

```
[len(x) for x in data if x!=""]
```

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the question. See my answer (and edit) for clarification.